# no puedo mostrar los generos de las peliculas de themoviedb api en Javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy batallando con esto hace 1 dia,
estoy utilizando vanilla js, esta seria la

```
const APIURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/moviesort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=acairiamiapi";

const SEARCHAPI = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie&api_key=acairiamiapi&query=";

const GENREAPI = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/listapi_key=acairiamiapi";
```

utilize funcion asincrona pero solamente para usar la APIURL Y SEARCHAPI cree una funcion showMovies donde puedo mostrar el titulo portada puntuacion pero el problema es que el link de APIURL solo tiene genre_ids el cual es un array de 2 o mas numeros, por ej [28, 18] o sea genero acción y drama
en cambio GENREAPI es un objeto que tiene un array de objetos por ej id: 28, name: "Action" me fije en su documentacion y foro y no encuentro la solucion

```
function showMovies(movies) {
main.innerHTML = "";
let movieEl = movies.map((movie) => {
const { poster_path, title, vote_average, overview, genre_ids } = movie;
return `<div class="movie">
        <img
            src="${IMGPATH + poster_path}"
            alt="${title}"
        />
        <div class="movie-info">
            <h3>${title}</h3>
            <span class="${getClassByRate(
   vote_average
   )}">${vote_average}</span>
             <div class="genre">${}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="overview">
            <h3>Overview:</h3>
            ${overview}
         </div>
         </div>
      `;
 });

 main.innerHTML = movieEl.join("");
}
```